# How to intercept refresh in Windows Forms WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using the Windows Forms `WebBrowser` control to display a generated report by setting `DocumentText`. Is there a way I can either prevent the user selecting "refresh" in the right-click menu, or intercept the refresh so that I can regenerate my report? At the moment the refresh method reloads "about:blank", discarding my report.

```
        Browser.AllowNavigation = true;
        Browser.DocumentText = "<head></head><body><h1>Test</h1></body>";
```

So far it seems that refresh does not cause a `Navigating` event, and I don't get a `DocumentCompleted` event, even though the control does replace the HTML content. I've tried both settings of `AllowNavigation`, with no visible difference.

Comment: You could disable the context menu (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.iswebbrowsercontextmenuenabled(v=vs.80).aspx) but the user can still press F5

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using the `OnKeyPress` event:

```
private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
       if(e == Keys.F5)
                //do sth;
}
```

In conjunction with what Simon Mourier said: [you could disable the context menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.iswebbrowsercontextmenuenabled%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. First `e == Keys.F5` doesn't compile, because function keys need to be matched in the `KeyDown` handler. I've tried binding to the `KeyDown` event on the browser, but my handler is never called.

Comment: It´s not a good anwer because you can click with right mouse button, and in the context menu you can just hit the refresh button!